# Is there a way to reload web pages with increasing numerical values?

Tags: reload

I want to reload a url with increasing numerical values so:
`www.example.com/page/1/`
turns into
`www.example.com/page/2/`and then `www.example.com/page/3/`
and so on.

Comment: Do you want to do this using Javascript?

Comment: Yes, if that could be possible

Comment: it sounds like you're trying to do some basic web-scraping, is that true?

Answer (score 0):

### Using Python

Need to install requests

```
pip install requests
```

#### get_ulrs.py:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.example.com/page'


for i in range(10):
    r = requests.get(
        f'{url}/{i}',
    )
   print(r.text)
```

#### run file

```
python3 ./get_ulrs.py
```

Comment: @KellyM be sure to accept the answer if it works for ya :)